# Automapper not invoking constructor

Tags: c#, automapper

I updated my app to Automapper 5.1.1 and I am seeing different behavior now.  When I instantiate an object like this:

```
PolicyEntity entity = mapper.Map<PolicyEntity>(template);
```

The `PolicyEntity` default constructor is no longer being invoked.

I couldn't find anything in the upgrade guide or release notes that seemed related; what am I missing?

I created my mapping like this:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<PolicyTemplate, PolicyEntity>()
        .ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition(c => c != null));
});
mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

`PolicyEntity` has the following constructors:

```
    public PolicyEntity() : base() { }

    public PolicyEntity(string name)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Do your maps use `ConstructUsing(...)`?

Comment: Sorry, should have included my mapping definition.  I've updated the question.

Comment: What constructors does `PolicyEntity` have defined?

Comment: @Amy updated question.

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/847) the issue?

Comment: I don't think so.  There are no errors, it successfully instantiates the objects and populates the mapped properties, but the initiation logic from the constructors is not being done.  Like it's somehow instantiating it without invoking either constructor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129287/discussion-between-benv-and-amy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding my answer [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1728).

Apparently the default parameter passed to the `ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition())` anonymous function changed, so my condition was failing, which meant AutoMapper was populating the properties of the target object even when the source value was null.

Changing my map definition to this fixed it:

```
.ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition((source, target, sourceValue, targetValue) => sourceValue != null));
```